# Getting "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'required' of null" when clicking submit in a form (validation with Angular)

Tags: angular, forms, validation, input

I am trying to add validation to a form. When I added the `userFormsErrors` part, the form started acting funny and I can't seem to solve the problem.

My first problem is that when clicking the button, `userFormErrors` returns true and then it stays true even if the user changes their input.

My second problem is that the email validation and password confirmation do not work (they used to work before I made these recent changes iirc).

My third problem is the error I'm getting `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'required' of null` when I click the submit button and then each time there's a change in the input fields (this is most probably related to my first problem).

Below is the code in register.component.html and register.component.ts

```html
    <form action="get" href="#" #userForm="ngForm">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 px-2">
          <div class="form-group formfields noselect">
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" [attr.placeholder]="'Enter Credential'" ngModel
              name="firstName" #firstName="ngModel" required="required" 
              [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': firstName.invalid && (firstName.dirty || firstName.touched) || userFormErrors }">
            <div class="invalid-credentials pl-3"
              *ngIf="firstName.invalid && (firstName.dirty || firstName.touched) || userFormErrors">
              <div *ngIf="firstName.errors.required">
                <p class="pt-2">Name is required</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 px-2">
          <div class="form-group formfields noselect">
            <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" [attr.placeholder]="'Enter Credential'" ngModel
              name="lastName" #lastName="ngModel" required="required"
              [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': lastName.invalid && (lastName.dirty || lastName.touched) || userFormErrors }">
            <div class="invalid-credentials pl-3"
              *ngIf="lastName.invalid && (lastName.dirty || lastName.touched) || userFormErrors">
              <div *ngIf="lastName.errors.required">
                <p class="pt-2">Error message here!</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 px-2">
          <div class="form-group formfields noselect">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" [attr.placeholder]="'Enter Credential'" ngModel
              name="email" #email="ngModel" required="required" pattern="/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/"
              [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': email.invalid && (email.dirty || email.touched) || userFormErrors }">
            <div class="invalid-credentials pl-3"
              *ngIf="email.invalid && (email.dirty || email.touched) || userFormErrors">
              <div *ngIf="email.errors.required">
                <p class="pt-2">Email is required!</p>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="email.errors.pattern">
                <p class="pt-2">You must type a valid email address!</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 px-2">
          <div class="formgroup formfields noselect">
            <label for="location">Location</label>
            <select class="w-100" id="location" ngModel name="location" #location="ngModel" required="required"
              [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': location.invalid && (location.dirty || location.touched) || userFormErrors }">
              <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.code">{{ country.name }}</option>
            </select>
            <img class="dropdown-icon d-inline" src="assets/images/icons/open-menu.svg">
            <div class="invalid-credentials pl-3"
              *ngIf="location.invalid && (location.dirty || location.touched) || userFormErrors">
              <div *ngIf="location.errors.required">
                <p class="pt-2">Error message here!</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 px-2">
          <div class="form-group formfields noselect">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" [attr.placeholder]="'Enter Credential'" ngModel
              name="password" #password="ngModel" required="required"
              [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': password.invalid && (password.dirty || password.touched) || userFormErrors }">
            <div class="invalid-credentials pl-3"
              *ngIf="password.invalid && (password.dirty || password.touched) || userFormErrors">
              <div *ngIf="password.errors.required">
                <p class="pt-2">Password is required!</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 px-2">
          <div class="form-group formfields noselect">
            <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" [attr.placeholder]="'Enter Credential'" ngModel
              name="confirmPassword" #confirmPassword="ngModel" required="required" nomatch="confirmassword.value != password.value"
              [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': confirmPassword.invalid && (confirmPassword.dirty || confirmPassword.touched) || userFormErrors}">
            <div class="invalid-credentials pl-3"
              *ngIf="confirmPassword.invalid && (confirmPassword.dirty || confirmPassword.touched) || userFormErrors">
              <div *ngIf="confirmPassword.errors.required">
                <p class="pt-2">Please retype your password!</p>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="confirmPassword.errors.nomatch">
                <p class="pt-2">Do not match</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100 sign-in-btn mx-2 my-3" href="#"
          (click)="onRegisterUser(userForm.valid, userForm.value)">Register</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const notFocused = false;
  }

  onRegisterUser(isValid, data){
    if(!isValid) {
     return this.userFormErrors = true;
    }
    console.log(isValid, data);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngModel.errors` can be `null` if your input is valid. Thus, you should check for `errors` before requesting the `required` field. You can do this with `?`, For example: `someField.errors?.required`.

If you need to update the `userFormErrors` by changing the input, you must add event listeners on change and update the `userFormErrors` whenever any input changes. But if you need to get the current `valid` status of the form, you can just get it from the `ngForm` directly.

Comment: Thanks. The first suggestion solved the console errors. The second part also steered me in the right direction. I used (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" within the opening form tag and it now checks all the invalid inputs individually. Thanks again for taking the time to respond.